# Does oral baking soda supplementation improve decreased thyroid function caused by resveratrol?

Tags: supplement, thyroid, baking-soda

Resveratrol, an antioxidant that has been linked to a [decrease in thyroid function](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28668442/) due to the suppression of certain thyroid genes related to the iodide uptake in thyrocytes.

Baking soda might be able to [improve the function of the thyroid](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21042013/).

Can taking an oral supplementation of baking soda negate and/or counteract the decrease in thyroid function caused by resveratrol?

Answer (score 2):

OK. I'll tackle your question in two parts....

The baking soda part:
If you've read the [source article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21042013/) cited by you till the end, you will understand that oral sodium bicarbonate, **through correction of metabolic acidosis**, improved thyroid function in CKD patients. So...the so called helpful effect which you've mentioned is seen only in patients with chronic kidney disease. It doesn't directly effect thyroid metabolism

The Resveratrol part:
Again in the [article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28668442/) cited by you, the said 'negative' effects were seen only in in-vitro cell lines. Not in humans. Even the in-vivo rat study showed no clinical effects (only biochemical and histological evidence of goitrogenic potential). These kinds of anti-oxidants are prescribed by doctors only after weighing the risks and benifits (like in case of cancer patients).
Remember:

> Only the right dose differentiates a drug from poison